# Swift 3. NSFetchedResultsController property in protocol

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift3

I have protocol with `NSFetchedResultsController` property

```
protocol ProtocolName {

  var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject> { get }

}
```

When I start to implement class with this protocol and change `NSManagedObject` to `EntityName`:

```
class MyClass: ProtocolName {

  var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<EntityName> { get }    
}
```

Xcode generates error: `Type 'MyClass' does not conform to protocol 'ProtocolName'`

Whether there is a correct way to implement a protocol with correct generic?

Comment: You need to initialize a concrete instance of the controller and return it in the implementation (preferable lazily instantiated )

Answer (score 1):

I fixed problem:

```
protocol ProtocolName {

  associatedtype T: NSFetchRequestResult

  var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<T> { get }

}
```

After adding `associatedtype` all stars work well

Comment: My protocol has @ objc because it is used on an @ IBOutlet property so I get "Associated type 'T' cannot be declared inside '@objc' protocol "